# How can I prevent forbidden dependencies in a monorepo based on npm workspaces and typescript project references?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, module, monorepo

I am trying to establish module boundaries on compile level in typescript/npm based monorepos but cannot find a way to achieve it. How can I prevent arbitrary imports violating module boundaries?

I use [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces) to define individual dependencies for the sub-projects. And I use [typescript project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to isolate the typescript compiler settings per project. The minimal example would be

```
/backend
  - /src
  - tsconfig.json
  - package.json
/frontend
  - /src
  - tsconfig.json
  - package.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
/node_modules
```

In this setting the frontend has exclusive dependencies (like react) other than the backend (like express.js). However, with npm workspaces both these dependencies end up in the same node_modules folder available for everyone.
Also this setting does not prevent the frontend project to import backend code and vice versa. How can I prevent these wrong imports already during typescript compilation?